# Pass data from 3 select's to one input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I've got three select fields (day, month, year). I need to pass their value automatically to one (at the hidden) input field (which will be transfered to database. The jquery code which i have wrote is bellow.

Unfortunatelly - it seems wrong/with error. How can I write it better to avoid such mistakes? currently data is not passed.Full code is here:

```js
var dd_value = document.getElementById("dd_value");
var mm_value = document.getElementById("mm_value");
var yy_value = document.getElementById("yy_value");
(dd_value+mm_value+yy_value).onchange = function(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("bdaysummary");
    textbox.value = dd_value;
};
```

```css
.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}
.visa{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);}
.mastercard{background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/SJbRQF7.png);}

.cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
            filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}

/* Extras */
a:visited{color:#888}
a{color:#444;text-decoration:none;}
p{margin-bottom:.3em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <p>Pick one of two:</p>
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
        <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <select id="dd_value">
            <option>- Day -</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select id="mm_value">
            <option>- Month -</option>
            <option value="0">Unknown</option>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">Nobember</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>     
         <select id="yy_value">
            <option>- Year -</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
            <option value="1946">1946</option>
            <option value="1945">1945</option>
            <option value="1944">1944</option>
            <option value="1943">1943</option>
            <option value="1942">1942</option>
            <option value="1941">1941</option>
            <option value="1940">1940</option>
            <option value="1939">1939</option>
            <option value="1938">1938</option>
            <option value="1937">1937</option>
            <option value="1936">1936</option>
            <option value="1935">1935</option>
            <option value="1934">1934</option>
            <option value="1933">1933</option>
            <option value="1932">1932</option>
            <option value="1931">1931</option>
            <option value="1930">1930</option>
            <option value="1929">1929</option>
            <option value="1928">1928</option>
            <option value="1927">1927</option>
            <option value="1926">1926</option>
            <option value="1925">1925</option>
            <option value="1924">1924</option>
            <option value="1923">1923</option>
            <option value="1922">1922</option>
            <option value="1921">1921</option>
            <option value="1920">1920</option>
            <option value="1919">1919</option>
            <option value="1918">1918</option>
            <option value="1917">1917</option>
            <option value="1916">1916</option>
            <option value="1915">1915</option>
            <option value="1914">1914</option>
            <option value="1913">1913</option>
            <option value="1912">1912</option>
            <option value="1911">1911</option>
            <option value="1910">1910</option>
            <option value="1909">1909</option>
            <option value="1908">1908</option>
            <option value="1907">1907</option>
            <option value="1906">1906</option>
            <option value="1905">1905</option>
            <option value="1904">1904</option>
            <option value="1903">1903</option>
            <option value="1902">1902</option>
            <option value="1901">1901</option>
            <option value="1900">1900</option>
        </select>   
        <br />
        <input name="bdaysummary" id="bdayummary" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When do you want to collect information from 3 selects ?

Comment: All the time. As you see each select has first option like: Day, Month, Year.I want display it in format: DD-MM-YYYY (including hyphens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. check inline comments for detailed explanation.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjfsayq7/1/)**

First I would like to add a `class` to your each select say `.bd` and write a change event to that `class`

```
$('.bd').on('change',function(){
    var allSelect=true; //for validation purpose
    $.each($('.bd'),function(){
        var value=$(this).find('option:selected').text();//store the current value
        if(value=='- Day -' || value=='- Month -' || value=='- Year -')
        //if value selected is any of these value then set allSelect=false
            allSelect=false
    });
    if(allSelect) //Proceed only if its true
    {
        var date=$('#dd_value option:selected').text(); //get date
        var month=$("#mm_value option:selected").text(); //get month
        var year=$("#yy_value option:selected").text(); //get year
        var newDate=date +"-"+month+"-"+year; //combine it
        $("#bdayummary").val(newDate); //display in textbox
    }
});
```

> **Note :** You can select date in any order but still validation happens

---

**UPDATE**

As per **[Hubert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445864/hubert-grzeskowiak)**'s comments I am updating this answer and DEMO too. Now this is taking `val()` and assigning the same.

**[DEMO UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjfsayq7/3/)**

```
$('.bd').on('change',function(){
    var allSelect=true;
    $.each($('.bd'),function(){
        var value=$(this).find('option:selected').val();
        if(value=='- Day -' || value=='- Month -' || value=='0' || value=='- Year -')
        {
           allSelect=false;
           return false; //to break loop if any found
        }
    });
    if(allSelect)
    {
        var date=$('#dd_value option:selected').val();
        var month=$("#mm_value option:selected").val();
        var year=$("#yy_value option:selected").val();
        if(month<10)
            month="0"+month;
        var newDate=date +"-"+month+"-"+year;
        $("#bdayummary").val(newDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of text of selected option better use the value (val).

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I could have used that but then since there isn't value for first option on select that would have not worked.. But yes infact that's the good option too.. But downvotes? Why.. Not asking to you though Hubert..

Comment: I've downvoted the answer, because going for option texts is mixing logic with view, which leads to various problems, e.g. i18n or any changes in view wording, or new invalid options (e.g. month 'Unknown') will break the code. Also the HTML code sample above has verbose months, but a numerical value as result is requested (see his comment).

Comment: Additional negative points: Unnecessary loop; no break on match in loop; no braces in if-statement; redundant element queries

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I've updated my answer... And yea I agree  on some of your points... This is one of the way and I don't think `$.each` is an unnecessary loop here and if there is only one line inside `if` statement then there is no need to wrap it up in braces..  Thanks for pointing and my suggestion to you that instead of posting 2 different answers just edit and update your answer...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually just learned that val() returns the text of an option if the option has no value attribute. That said my answer probably wouldn't work as it is. +1 for this. You are also probably right in the point that I should have edited my answer instead of creating a new one - I posted a new answer because the solution is a wholly different one. Regarding the loop I guess it's okay, but since you define specific elements by id  in the last lines you effectively select all the option elements twice: once in a loop and once outside.

Comment: And leaving out braces is no error, but it's considered bad style because it's a common source of bugs

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Reduce in number of lines increases application performance.. So whenever you get chance reduce number of lines.. If statement actually doesn't require braces if it can be done in single line.. You can google on this.. Thanks for your comments..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88211/discussion-between-hubert-grzeskowiak-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dd_value, #mm_value, #yy_value').change(function(){
        dd_value = $('#dd_value').val();
        mm_value = $('#mm_value').val();
        yy_value = $('#yy_value').val();
        result = dd_value+'-'+mm_value+'-'+yy_value;
        $('#bdayummary').val(result);
    });
})
</script>
```

**Recommendation:**
Use zero fill format for days and months numbers (for example 01 instead of 1) to prevent unwanted behaviors.

**Notice:**
As Hubert said too, you must think about a solution for the first options that don't have valid value. This code is focused only on gathering data from select inputs and putting them inside another input.

Comment: This is almost perfect, except you might want to look up if the value is valid (e.g. not the 1st default placeholder option)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in

```
(dd_value+mm_value+yy_value).onchange  = function() {...}
```

The "+" operator on elements coerces the elements to strings and concatenates them. So basically you're assigning the "onchange" property to a string, not the the elements. Assign them one by one or use jQuery like this:

```
$([dd_value, mm_value, yy_value]).change(function() {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that (jQuery):

```
$(dd_value, mm_value, yy_value).on('change', function(){
   ....
});
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap the nodes in an array so that jQuery actually selects them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yy_value,#dd_value,#mm_value").change(function() {
var dd_value = $("#dd_value").val();
var mm_value = $("#mm_value").val();
var yy_value = $("#yy_value").val();
alert(dd_value+"-"+mm_value+"-"+yy_value); 
});
```

Try This Code This Will Work For You should include jquery for this 
**Edit**

```
if(dd_value != '- Day -' && mm_value !='- Month -' && yy_value != '- Year -')
        {
            alert(dd_value+"-"+mm_value+"-"+yy_value);  
        }
```

**To**

`alert(dd_value+"-"+mm_value+"-"+yy_value);`

due to `change` function this will be evaluated only when all fields are change as 
`$("#yy_value,#dd_value,#mm_value").change(function() {});` so this will resolve this

Comment: You probably want to attach the change listener to all three select elements, not only to year

Answer (score 0):

This is basically Mohammad's answer extended by some value checks and zero-padding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dd_value, #mm_value, #yy_value').change(function(){
        var dd_value = $('#dd_value').val();
        var mm_value = $('#mm_value').val();
        var yy_value = $('#yy_value').val();
        var result = "";
        // check that the values are not undefined (missing value)
        if ($.inArray("undefined", [ typeof dd_value, typeof mm_value, typeof yy_value ]) < 0)
        {
            // add padding zero
            dd_value = dd_value.length === 1 ? "0"+dd_value : dd_value;
            mm_value = mm_value.length === 1 ? "0"+mm_value : mm_value;
            var result = dd_value+'-'+mm_value+'-'+yy_value;
        }
        $('#bdayummary').val(result);
    });
})
```